# jquery not triggering for ENTER Keydown

Tags: keydown

i guess I'm missing something I've checked my code and its pretty much the same as another project where it works fine. [the repository](http://github.com/sbrycebarker/todoapp)

first is what is in my jquery file

```
`$("#taskdata").keyup(function(event){
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
    console.log("getting band")
    $("#getband").click();
   }
});`
```

a directive it is in
`

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('newTask', function() {
return {
restrict: 'E',
template: `
<div class="newTask" style:" margin: 0;">
<input id="taskdata" class="data" name="task" ng-model="text" 
placeholder="Enter Task">

<button class="submit" ng-click="postData( {text:text} )">Create Task</button>
</div> `
```

}

}) 
`

Comment: If you're looking for keydown? Why is the event for keyup?

Comment: thanks ill change that

Comment: how do i make this work within a directive?

Comment: looks like i figured it out